# Ruby on Rails presence of an error in a specific field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm defining the validation of some of my fields present in a table called "Contacts":

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :nome, :cognome, :indirizzo_abitazione, 
              :numero_civico, :indirizzo_email, :prefisso_cellulare, :cellulare, presence: true
    validates :nome, :cognome, :indirizzo_email, 
              :prefisso_cellulare, :cellulare, uniqueness: true
    validates :indirizzo_email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, on: :create }
end
```

I want to exploit the bootstrap's class attribute 'has-error' to highlight a specific field in red if an error is present; so I tried to do this in this way:

```
  <div class="form-group <%= @contact.errors[:name] ? "has-error" : "" %>" >
    <%= f.label :name , :class => "control-label" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
```

But when I log to this page the field is already red. Is there a method to see if, during the validation of one record, a specific field presents an error?

Comment: `<div class="form-group" + <%= @contact.errors[:name] ? "has-error" : "" %> >` try this

Comment: <div class="form-group" has-error ="" +=""></div> this is the result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@contact.errors[:name]` returns an array of messages, if no messages are inside then `@contact.errors[:name]` will return only an empty array. An array is an object so your statement will always yield `"has-error"`.

This will work:

```
<%= @contact.errors[:name].present? ? "has-error" : "" %>
```

Comment: this was close to the soluction but it still doesn't work. it always assign the "" attribute to the class

Answer (score 0):

With `@contact.errors[:name] ? "has-error" : ""`, you're printing `has-error` if `@contact.errors[:name]` is not nil. I think it's just empty.

Try to do `@contact.errors[:name].blank? ? "" : "has-error"` which means if it's blank (equivalent to 'is nil or empty'), don't add the class, else add the required class.

Comment: whit this method the class is directly assigned to the field when you load the page